# Set borders to a range if first cell in row is not empty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to set borders to a range in row if first cell in this row is not empty.

I have this code:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var sheetmon = ss.getSheetByName('Monitor'); 
  var rows = sheetmon.getRange('G59:P90'); 
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows(); 
  var values = rows.getValues(); 
  var testvalues = sheetmon.getRange('G59:G90').getValues(); 

  rows.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false, "red", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM); 

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
      var n = i + 1;
      if (testvalues[i] > 0) { 
        sheetmon.getRange('a' + n + ':g' + n).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "red", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM); 
      }
  }
}
```

But it works only for the first row in range G59:G90

Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set borders in the same row that is being evaluated in the loop, you must change the value of `n` to always be 59 greater than `i`.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetmon = ss.getSheetByName('Monitor'); 
  var rows = sheetmon.getRange('G59:P90'); 
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows(); 
  var values = rows.getValues(); 
  var testvalues = sheetmon.getRange('G59:G90').getValues(); 

  rows.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false, "red", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM); 

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
      var n = i + 59;
      Logger.log(testvalues[i] > 0);
      if (testvalues[i] > 0) {
        Logger.log(testvalues[i]);
        sheetmon.getRange('A' + n + ':G' + n).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "red", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM); 
      }
  }
```

Comment: I've got the logic. I modified the code a little bit for my needs and now it works perfectly! thanks

Answer (score 1):

testvalues is a two dimensional array.  So this

```
if (testvalues[i] > 0) { 
        sheetmon.getRange('a' + n + ':g' + n).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "red", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM); 
      }
```

should be something like this:

```
if (testvalues[i][0] > 0) { 
        sheetmon.getRange('a' + n + ':g' + n).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "red", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_MEDIUM); 
      }
```

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())